# DocuSign eWitness functionality

Tags: docusignapi

With DocuSign Witness functionality,in which sender can add field **Sign With Witness** and sends envelope to signer.Signer will add witness details and complete form.The witness will get notification and completes form.Is this functionality supports when Deeds are signed and they are required to be witnessed by law?

I noticed new eWitness functionality.Have anyone used it?Is there a use case,form, region or industry that the new eWitness functionality was specifically designed for?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-sign-with-witness please read this for more information about this feature. 
**Note:** This is not the same as eNotary, which is allowed in several states as an alternative to having documents notarized by a person.